# Fail to change the label text with a timer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

As a swift beginner, I'm building a simple app which will get data from a website to update the label text.

In the ViewController.swift I begin with a function called requestCycle():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestCycle()
}
```

In this requestCycle() function I create a timer to call the http request function basicAuthHttpRequest():

```
    func requestCycle(){
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.basicAuthHttpRequest), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
    RunLoop.current.add(self.timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes);
}
```

In the basicAuthHttpRequest() function, I set up an http request to get data from a url, and use the data to update the label text:

```
...
    //http request, parse json, store the data in TempIn 
    let TempInString = String(describing: TempIn!)
    self.TempInLabel.text = TempInString
    print(TempInString)
    print(self.TempInLabel.text!)
...
```

When I run the app, the data will be printed("33" and Optional("33")) and NO ERRORs occur. However, the text of the label shown is not changed at all.
If I use a button to trigger the function basicAuthHttpRequest(), after clicking the button, the label text will be changed in a few seconds.

What's wrong with my poor timer? =.=

Comment: Please update label text with main thread. DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
self.TempInLabel.text = TempInString as String
})

Comment: Try to do it main thread//http request, parse json, store the data in Temp In 
```DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let TempInString:String = String(describing: TempIn!)
    self.TempInLabel.text = TempInString as String
    print(TempInString as Any)
    print(self.TempInLabel.text as Any)
            }```

Comment: Why do you bridge cast `String` to `String` and later `TempInString` to `Any`? That's both nonsensical. And do not add the timer to the run loop. The method `scheduledTimer` does that implicitly.

Comment: because when I directly write "print(TempInString)", there'll be a warning. so I take the advise from Xcode to add "as Any" at the end. thanks for ur advice, I'll fix it.

Comment: `TempInString` is non-optional. There can't be a warning in the line to print it. And please consider the naming convention that property and variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update text on the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let TempInString:String = String(describing: TempIn!)
    self.TempInLabel.text = TempInString as String
}
```

Comment: But what's the difference between changing the text from a ButtonClick and from a timer? Why I need DispatchQueue when I use a timer to change the UI?

Comment: When you are in a timer completion block, you are not on the main thread. But you can change UI elements only from the main thread. You can take a look here for more informations about threading : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i

Comment: Useful website. Thx u XD

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :-

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { self.TempInLabel.text = TempInString as String })
```

Comment: It works. ThxXD. btw, what's the difference between changing the text from a ButtonClick and from a timer? Why I need DispatchQueue when I use a timer to change the UI?

Comment: When you are changing text from ButtonClick at that time it will work on main thread or some more priority based thread compare to background thread. So when you call with timer it is working on background thread which is not update the UILabel value as soon as possible. and ButtonClick update the UILabel value.

Comment: More precisely, all UI changes MUST be made on the main UI thread.  Your timer callback is executing in a different thread, so you need to use the DisparchQueue to change it back to the main thread itself.  Also note that when using scheduledTimer you don't need (read should not) add the timer to a RunLoop, it's already been done for you.

Comment: Nice answer and so specific! Thx u

Comment: If you satisfy then don't forget to accept answer or give to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The timer is running on background thread. so you have to update label value with main thread. You have to use below code for the same.

```
self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(updateUI), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)

func updateUI() {
    print("here update your UI")
}
```

Also you can do with `OperationQueue.`

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
    print("here update your UI")            
})
```